# How to buy and send sms to unverified phone numbers using twilio api

Tags: laravel, sms

Am currently developing a web application using Laravel. I have been using twilio trial account to send messages to just one verified phone number and now I want to launch the application and be able to send sms to any phone number filled on the registration page and send an sms to the user after successfully registration. How do i do this to accomplish my task and move on because I am stack and don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

I believe Twilio has a limit on whitelisted numbers during the trial period.

Many SMS Gateway providers do this to prevent spammers.

Nexmo, where I work, has an SMS API allows you to easily send SMS messages to phones in over 200 countries.

The API is extremely reliable, safe, & easy to integrate in your application.

All you need to do is make a simple HTTP call.

After signing up for the free trial, there will be a screen in the dashboard where you are allowed to enter up to 10 whitelisted numbers during the trial phase.

Once you top up (reload your account with funds), this restriction is lifted.

[Here](https://developers.nexmo.com/Quickstarts/sms/send/) is some more information on how to integrate it the SMS API with PHP